# HTML string (&nbsp;) breaking JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm collecting some data from my page, storing the data in an array for multiple uses on the page, and sending a copy of the array via AJAX, storing the data in the database on a PHP page.

One piece of data I'm storing in the array is the output of a TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor, so it contains HTML, but have just found this to be a problem - I'll explain:

After entering one line of text in my WYSIWYG editor and I trigger my AJAX event, this is the JSON string displayed in my console and everything worked okay, the database was sent and stored:

```
{"id":"229","topic":"","title":"","description":"","content":"<p>fgfgfdg.</p>","keywords":""}
```

If I write two lines of text, this is the JSON string and was successful:

```
{"id":"229","topic":"","title":"","description":"","content":"<p>fgfgfdg.</p>\n<p>fgfgfdg</p>","keywords":""}
```

Now, if I write one line of text and press return and not type anything on the second line, I get the following which fails.

```
{"id":"229","topic":"","title":"","description":"","content":"<p>fgfgfdgdfgdfgdfgdfg.</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>","keywords":""}
```

It seems `&nbsp;` broke my JSON output somehow. My PHP can't access the decoded array values, as there is no array. `print_r(json_decode($json))` returns nothing. Can anybody help?

**This is my HTML page with jQuery:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<script>
var post_data = {};

post_data.id = post_id;
post_data.topic = topic;
post_data.title = title;
post_data.description = description;
post_data.content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
post_data.keywords = keywords;

post_data = JSON.stringify(post_data);

save_post_request = $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/save-post.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: "save_mode="+save_mode+"&post_data="+post_data,
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false
});
</script>
```

**This is my PHP page:**

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

$post_data = isset($_POST['post_data']) ? $_POST['post_data'] : null;
$post_data_arr = json_decode($post_data, true);
$post_id = $post_data_arr['id'];
$topic = $post_data_arr['topic'];
// others
$content = $post_data_arr['content'];

if (!$post_data_arr['id']) {
    // fails here
    // id is not accessible when the JSON contains <p>&nbsp;</p> in the 'content' item
}
```

**This is what Firebug says:**

[image]

Comment: What does a `var_dump($_POST['post_data'])` show? See if the JSON's mangled there. If it is, then something in your jquery code is mangling it on the client side

Comment: @MarcB, thanks for your help, but solved now thanks to Qunetin. Liking the use of 'mangled' and 'mangling' :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are placing the JSON into some URL Encoded data, but you are not URL Encoding it.

The `&` character has special meaning in URL Encoded data (it separates key/value pairs), so this means you are breaking the data.

Use the `encodeURIComponent` function to properly encode your data before adding it to the string:

```
data: "save_mode="+encodeURIComponent(save_mode)+"&post_data="+encodeURIComponent(post_data),
```

However, since you are using jQuery, you shouldn't be constructing your URL Encoded data by hand in the first place. jQuery can do it for you. Pass `data` an object instead of a string:

```
data: {
    save_mode: save_mode,
    post_data: post_data
},
```

Comment: Pulls yet more hair from already balding head. Why didn't I think of that?! Thanks, Quentin. +1 for response time.